# Hibernate @ManyToOne mapping error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Good day to you. I have 2 tables.

```
 CREATE TABLE A(
  id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR2(255) NULL,
  category VARCHAR2(255) NULL,
  is_hidder NUMBER(1) NULL,
  is_enabled NUMBER(1) NULL,
  b_id NUMBER(10) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_a PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_to_b
  FOREIGN KEY (vj_users_preferences_id)
  REFERENCES VJ_USER_PREFERENCES(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE B(
  ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  EXT_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  KEY VARCHAR2(1024) NOT NULL,
  VALUE VARCHAR2(1024) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_B PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

For both tables I have entities and I want to map them @OneToOne.

```
class Entity A{
    .......
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="pk_b", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private B b;
}
```

Entity B is Audited and haven't got A field so connection is unidirectional. When I try to persist the A entity I got the error:

> Caused By: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine type of dynamic map entity

This exception is being thrown from:

> org.hibernate.tuple.entity.DynamicMapEntityTuplizer.BasicEntityNameResolver#resolveEntityName

Because the input is Map and it has not got: DynamicMapInstantiator.KEY in it.

Can somebody help me with this issue? I cannot figure out why Hibernate is creating that map without necessary value. Is there something wrong with my mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that my UI form was receiving over 50 symbols, but database had:
  `EXT_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL`
When I altered table to reflect UI possibilities (e.g. EXT_ID NUMBER(50) NOT NULL) then error was gone.

That exception, as per my understanding, is misleading in this kind of situation. I was expecting to see: SQLGrammarException of kind of it.
Hope this will help oneday.